# Trying to run python script in PHP

Tags: python, php, perl

I'm trying to run a Python script inside a perl script with the following command:

```
system("python3 script.py -d http:\/\/site.com --no-interaction");

qx/python3 script.py -d http:\/\/site.com --no-interaction/;
```

On the operating system's command line, the Python script executes, but when I make a call from a PHP application, the perl work, but the python script don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you get any error message from Perl side?
Likely where your PHP/Perl script runs from isn't the same location as where script.py is at. Try by using full path to Python script. Also double check that python3 is in your $PATH.

For example:
-> cat /home/me/python/script.py

```
print("This line will be printed.")
```

-> cat /home/me/perl/pytest.pl

```
#!/bin/env perl
print "From perl:\n";
system ("python3 /home/me/python/script.py");
```

```
cd /home/me/perl/
ksh
whence python3
"/usr/bin"
pytest.pl
"From perl:
 This line will be printed."
```

Comment: For the script to run required the full path of python and perl.